# Duplicate foreign and primary keys in Chen's notation

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Hello good people of StackOverflow, I have a question pertaining to entity-relationship diagrams today, specifically ones in Chen's notation.

My question is thus: If I have two entities, say [User] and [Bid], that are connected by a 1-to-many relationship, do I need to include the duplicate UserID key on [Bid] since it already exists in [User]?

Here is an image of the diagram with duplicate keys: [Duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8xsY.png)

Here is an image of the diagram without duplicate keys:
[No duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L93pY.png)

Which is the correct format to use? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the image with the duplicates are foreign keys but I don't know any ERM with foreign keys.

The diagram should be the secound without duplicates.

You can look at Wikipedia for the "correct" format:
[Chens_notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)

Comment: So, in this case the foreign key is "implied" by the relationship connecting the two entities?

Comment: That's true, as you mentioned relationship between two entities is enough to show where you need foreign keys later.